# Understanding int reversing logic

Tags: c++, reverse, palindrome

I'm new to C++.
So I found this reverse code on the internet. My prof. told me to make a palindrome checker, so I look for the reverse first.
Here is what I made

```
void main() 
{
    int num;
    int new_num = 0;
    int dummy;

    cout << "Masukkan angka";
    cin >> num;

    dummy = num;
    cout << dummy << endl;

    while (num > 0)
    {
        new_num = new_num*10 + (num % 10);
        num = num/10;
    }
    cout << new_num << endl;

    if ( new_num == dummy)
    {
        cout << "true";
    }
    else 
        cout<<"false";

    getch();
}
```

The most confusing part is this

```
while(num > 0)
{
    new_num = new_num*10 + (num % 10);
    num = num/10;
}
cout << new_num << endl;
```

I found this on the internet and I don't know how it works.
Can someone explain how this code can reverse the number I input? Like when I input 12345, the output would be 54321. I can't understand.

Comment: Try using a debugger or drawing with pencil and paper.

Comment: Look up for _modulus operation_ , _multiplication_, _division_ and _addition_, and some basics how the decimal numbers system works.

Comment: *10, %10 and /10 operations typically signify operations on decimal digits.

Comment: Do you understand the expression `% 10`?

Comment: Try putting a print here `while(num > 0) { cout << (num % 10) << (num / 10) << new_num << endl; new_num = new_num*10 + (num % 10); num = num/10;}`

Comment: Horrible formatting, and no idea how much you need explained: unclear/too broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its talking the last char of your input by using modulo.

**input is:** `12345`

**Cycle 1:**

1. new_num is 0, multiply by 10 give 0.
2. add modulo or your input `12345 % 10 = 5`, new_num is now 5.
3. divide your input by 10 to remove last digit. `input = 1234`

**Cycle 2,3,4 etc.:**

1. new_num is 5, multiply by 10 gives 50.
2. add modulo or your input `1234 % 10 = 4`, new_num is now 54.
3. divide your input by 10 to remove last digit. `input = 123`

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the liberty to modify your source, and provide it in a more readable format

```
int inputNumber = 123;
int reversedNumber = 0;

cout << "The input number is " << inputNumber << endl;

while (inputNumber > 0) {
    reversedNumber = reversedNumber*10 + inputNumber%10;
    inputNumber = inputNumber/10;
}
cout << "The reversed number is " << reversedNumber << endl;
```

First of all, always use meaningful variables. 
It will be more helpful while reading your code.

**Now on to the explanation**, 
The modulo operator gives the remainder (not quotient!) of a division, 
i.e. 5%2 = 1. 
In the while loop, 
1) We keep over-writing `reversedNumber` by changing (increasing) its decimal position (multiply by 10) and adding the **remainder** of the division of `inputNumber` and `10` 
2) We over-write `reversedNumber` by changing (decreasing) its decimal position (divide by 10).

I encourage you to actually trace out the program on paper, or printing the variable's values (debugging?) to see how this operation works.

Answer (score -1):

First take a look at what `num % 10` does:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << " % 10 = " << i % 10 << '\n';
  }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d26b893682b0001

Do you see the pattern? This expression basically just gets the least significant decimal digit from a number.

You should know the pattern in `new_num*10` without even looking, since we learned this in elementary school math: It shifts the digits to the left one place.

Then if you think about what addition will do in this case, `new_num*10 + num % 10`, you should see that adding a number in the range [0..9] to an integer where the lowest digit is zero, will just replace that zero with the new digit.

`num/10` shifts digits to the right, and since it's using integral division the fractional parts are discarded.

So all together we have:

```
int remove_last_digit(int value) { return value / 10; }

int get_last_digit(int value) { return value % 10; }

int push_digit(int value, int digit) {
  return value * 10 + digit;
}

bool has_more_digits(int value) { return value != 0; }

int reverse_int(int value) {
  int reversed_value = 0;
  while ( has_more_digits(value)) {
    reversed_value = push_digit(reversed_value, get_last_digit(value));
    value = remove_last_digit(value);
  }
  return reversed_value;
}
```

Think of a number as digits piled on top of each other. If you take the top digit and put it on top of a second pile, and keep doing that until the first pile is empty, then the digits in the second pile are now stacked in the reverse order.